# django how can i display multiple pictures by id inside multiple items

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

i have 2 classes in my
models.py

```js
class Product(models.Model):
ext...
and
class ProductImage(models.Model):
product=models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image=models.ImageField
views.py
```

```js
def view_property(request, id):
    photo = get_object_or_404(ProductImage, id=id)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    photos = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product)
    context = {
        'photo':photo,
        'product':product,
        'photos': photos
    }
    return render(request,'products/view_property.html', context)
```

so to display multiple images in my html page i include **int:id** or samthing like that in the url.py
url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path( '<int:id>/' , views.view_property , name = 'view_property' ),
]
```

Now when I want to fetch data to my view_property.html page, I get the images filtered fine by ID, so it works, but the problem is in my view_property.html page On the page I have items, each item contains the product and pictures in the slider so i want to fetch multiple products each product fetch his images filtred by id
view_property.html

```
    <div class="box-container">
        {% for pro in products %}
        <div class="box">
            <div class="image-container">
                {% for img in photos %}
                <div class="mySlides"><img src="{{img.image.url}}" alt=""></div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="location">
                    <p>apartments</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

her i get all images of one product same thing with each items because i fetching data of one product from url int:id

I think the changes will be in url.py views.py
i hope i get an answer

i try to delete the  from the url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path( 'view_property/' , views.view_property , name = 'view_property' ),
]
```

and i want to add **int:id** inside the view_property.html page exactly inside the for loop but i dont know howe but i try this for example:

```
    <div class="box-container">
        {% for pro in products ***<int:id>***%}
        <div class="box">
            <div class="image-container">
                {% for img in photos %}
                <div class="mySlides"><img src="{{img.image.url}}" alt=""></div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="location">
                    <p>apartments</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product', default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product_images', default='')
```

**views.py**

```
def view_property(request, id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    photos = ProductImage.objects.all().filter(product=product.id)
    context = {
        'photo': product.image,
        'product': product,
        'photos': photos
    }
    return render(request,'products/view_property.html', context)
```

**view_property.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product Detail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Product Image:
    </p>
    <img src="{{photo.url}}" alt="" srcset="">
    <p>
        {{product}}
    </p>
    <p>
        Product Images:
    </p>
    {% for i in photos %}
        <img src="{{i.image.url}}" alt="" srcset="">
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i try your method and i get this <<<missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'>>> and after I add id in the urls.py nothing is happend

Comment: The provided code is running without any issues on my end. Could you please share the updated code, or will you please cross check the code and run that again?